# How to test website for different devices from tablets to desktops and anything in between?

Tags: user-interface, screen, usability

Is there some online tool that i can use to test website  for devices ranging from  tablets to  desktops and anything in between like netbooks and laptops ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ProtoFluid Is Awesome , I Just Love It

http://protofluid.com/

http://viewlike.us/

http://www.infobyip.com/testwebsiteresolution.php

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [link](http://sixrevisions.com/tools/10-excellent-tools-for-testing-your-site-on-mobile-devices/)  that might help out.

I use many of those.

Google is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using Ripple (http://ripple.tinyhippos.com/) and it's been joyous so far.

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this site. Looks pretty good.

[Screenfly](http://quirktools.com/screenfly/)